# Create bootable iso file from rootfs linux files

Tags: linux, files, boot, grub, iso

I want to make bootable iso file from typical Linux distributive files. I have tried to make grub bootloader, firstly I created template for grub.cfg using `grub-mkconfig` and I added this configuration at start of it:

```
set default=0
set timeout=5

menuentry "LinuxTest" {
    set root=(hd0)
    linux /boot/bzImage root=/dev/sda1
}
```

Then I used `grub-mkrescue -o /path/to/file.iso /path/to/linux/files`

But when I'm trying to boot it up, it says 'error: unknown filesystem'

What I did wrong/didn't do to make it work?

[image: Linux Files]

[image: ls in grub-cli]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text in your second image reproduced:

```
grub> ls
(proc) (hd0) (cd) (cd,apple4) (cd,apple3) (cd,apple2) (cd,apple1) (cd,gpt4) (cd,gpt3) (cd,gpt2) (cd,gpt1)
grub> _
```

UEFI is not BIOS: the system won't always arrange the current boot media to be `(hd0)` for GRUB. In this case, it looks like the boot media might have been recognized as `(cd)`.

Your very simple GRUB configuration snippet attempts to read `(hd0)` as a single unpartitioned device, but it looks like that is an empty unpartitioned disk, or perhaps something partitioned in some way that is not recognizable to GRUB's GPT partitioning detection module.

Your GRUB configuration snippet isn't even self-consistent: assuming that the Linux kernel would see `(hd0)` as `/dev/sda` (which is not guaranteed by any means!), the `set root=(hd0)` suggests that there would be a filesystem on `/dev/sda` that would contain the path `/boot/bzImage`.

On the other hand, the Linux kernel boot parameter `root=/dev/sda1` suggests `/dev/sda` would be partitioned, and that the root filesystem would be on the first partition.

Either `/dev/sda` is unpartitioned and contains just a single filesystem covering the whole disk/image, or it is partitioned and `/dev/sda1` is the first partition; both of them cannot be simultaneously true.

For an educational experience, I recommend that you try attaching the ISO image produced by `grub-mkrescue` to a loop device, and investigate the contents of any partitions detected within:

```
ls /dev/loop*
sudo losetup -P --show -f /path/to/file.iso
ls /dev/loop*          # you might see more than one new device!
file -s /dev/loop*     # to identify the filesystem types within
```

The `losetup` command will output a `/dev/loopX` style loop device name, but it will actually create loop devices for any partitions contained within too. Note the number in place of X, and substitute it in place of `X` in any of the following commands:

Try `fdisk -l /dev/loopX`: the apparently-single ISO file actually contains a valid GPT partition table, that will look something like this (partition sizes may be different):

```
# fdisk -l /dev/loop0
Disk /dev/loop0: 13,22 MiB, 13867008 bytes, 27084 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7FB1CA87-86D8-4C32-A49D-F5CEB184C045

Device       Start   End Sectors  Size Type
/dev/loop0p1    64   251     188   94K Microsoft basic data
/dev/loop0p2   252  6011    5760  2,8M EFI System
/dev/loop0p3  6012 26435   20424   10M Apple HFS/HFS+
/dev/loop0p4 26436 27035     600  300K Microsoft basic data
```

This is because it is not just a plain old ISO-9660 image, but a *hybrid ISO-9660/hard disk image*. This is a very common trick with Linux-related ISO images.

If you use `fdisk /dev/loopX` and then use the `i` command of `fdisk` to get more information about the partitions, you'll see that the "Microsoft basic data" partitions are named `Gap0` and `Gap1` respectively, suggesting that they are there just to hide the ISO-9660 filesystem metadata and whatever else needs to be hidden from the "hard-disk-image" view.

The EFI System partition contains a filesystem of the FAT family, and contains just a single file: `efi/boot/bootx64.efi`.

The Apple HFS+ partition contains a copy of your `/path/to/linux/files`, with a few extra files sprinkled in: a `boot/grub/` directory hierarchy with a full set of GRUB modules, and a `System/Library/CoreServices/` directory containing `boot.efi` and `SystemVersion.plist`, the former of which is identical to the `bootx64.efi` file on the EFI System partition.

That `bootx64.efi`/`boot.efi` is GRUB for the 64-bit UEFI architecture, with support for MBR, GPT and old macOS partitioning built-in, and embedded configuration to load more modules to support even exotic partition types if possible. (Basically, it is configured to load all the `boot/grub/x86_64-efi/part_*.mod` GRUB module files in alphabetical order if it can.)

With `isoinfo -i /path/to/file.iso`, we can find out that `grub-mkrescue` sets the ISO-9660 filesystem label to `ISOIMAGE`, so at the very least, you should have set your GRUB configuration snippet like this:

```
set default=0
set timeout=5

menuentry "LinuxTest" {
    search --label --set root "ISOIMAGE"
    linux /bzImage root=/dev/sda
}
```

That should make GRUB search for a filesystem by label, and make it the new root for any subsequent file path references.

From your first picture I see the `bzImage` file is not in the `/boot` directory but in the root directory of the ISO-9660 filesystem, so the pathname needed to be fixed too.

And finally, the root filesystem parameter for the kernel can be difficult. Since you are not using an initramfs, there are some restrictions on how the root filesystem can be specified: you can only use `/dev/*` names, `PARTUUID=` syntax or `PARTLABEL=` syntax, not filesystem labels.

Your root filesystem content is accessible as a ISO-9660 filesystem on the whole-disk device, which unfortunately excludes `PARTUUID=` and `PARTLABEL=`.

An alternative way to access it would be as a HFS+ filesystem on the 3rd partition using `PARTLABEL=HFSPLUS` (as revealed by the `i` command of `fdisk /dev/loopX`), but I rather doubt you had the foresight to include Apple HFS+ filesystem support into your kernel image.

GRUB's `ls` command revealed that your system has one more HDD in addition to the CD/image, so depending on what storage drivers you have included in your `bzImage` and in what order they are probed by the system, either `root=/dev/sda` or `root=/dev/sdb` might work.

This might be enough for a one-off, hacked-together bootable media, but if you need this to work on multiple systems, a more robust solution would be needed. In that case, I would recommend not trying to use `grub-mkrescue` for a purpose it isn't designed for, and instead first setting up separate images USB stick/hard disk boot and CD-ROM/DVD boot, if you need them both. Trying to hybridize them into a single image that does both will be easier once you are more familiar of the differences between booting from a hard disk vs. booting from a CD/DVD media.